# how to force manual merge with git instead of fast forward

Tags: git

I created a branch to solve an issue. In this branch I put many debug lines to identify the problem and I fixed it. So I have:

```
* (issue_b47)    Without the bug but with a lot of useless debug things
* (HEAD, master) With the bug
```

If I simply write this

```
git checkout master
git merge issu_b47
```

git will do a fast forward merge and I will then inherit all the debug things I don't want.

What I would like to do is to do a manual merge with my `difftool`. How to do it?

I think it easier to clearly see on the left panel of my difftool the `issue_b47` branch and on the right panel the `master` branch. I can just decide to keep what is relevant to solve the issue, save the diff and finalize the merge. Is there any to do it so with git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using this command you can avoid fast forward

```
git merge --no-ff branchname
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you want the commit on the branch to be altered a bit. There's many ways to do that. Here are a couple common ones:

1. Fix up the contents (get rid of the debug stuff), then `git add -A; git commit --amend` on your branch, then merge as normal.
2. `git reset --soft HEAD~1` while on the branch, then `git reset HEAD .`, will pull everything back out and let you start the commit over again. You will have unstaged changes.

Comment: The first solution is what I usually do but It would be much better to do a diff with incriminated files of both branches. I will clearly see what changes I made. With this method I can just keep what is relevant to solve the issue.

Comment: I don't think there is anyway to do that with git. You might get what you want with `git reset --soft HEAD~1; git reset HEAD .; git add -p`, The last bit will cause git to take each chunk of the change and ask you if you want to add it to the commit.

Comment: @coin This is a great example why someone should embrace the principle [Commit Often, Perfect Later, Publish Once](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/). That won't help you now, but you should consider it for your future workflow.

Answer (score 0):

From iss_b47 branch

```
git difftool HEAD~1 -- <file>
```

Presuming you have a suitable difftool configured you will get a side by side pane where you can move changes back and forth and then save the result.  At that point you can `git commit --amend` and then git merge.

In the off change you happened to do `git commit` on just your debug changes and then did `git commit --amend` with the bug fix then you can use the reflog to extract the changes automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use --no-commit to force no commit, and --squash to create it's own commit rather than the same commit as (issue_b47)

```
git merge --no-commit --squash issu_b47
```

After this command, git will do the auto-merge and put the modified files in INDEX. You can find the modified files by *git status*.

At this stage you can use whatever tool to do your manual merge. After that git add + git commit to finish your merge. You will get a separate commit from the issue_b47 as it used to be in fast forward (which is normal because they have different changes in both commits)